# is there any way to make a login database without using php in a website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, authentication, web

I am making a mental health website and I want to make a working sign in and login page. The code editor I am using does not accept php files. its replit and its online.

Is there any other method that I can use or do I have to change the editor?

please let me know.

Comment: #1 What is your stack: java, nodejs, python, c# ? #2 What code editor are you using?

Comment: I am a high school student. I am using html, css and javascript.  the code editor is replit

Comment: Reviewing your web ide: it says that support 50+ languages. If you want to implement a login feature, you will need at least: #1 Data: users ( user, password, etc) , roles (admin, guest, etc) #2 Backend language: I advice you nodejs which is based on javascript. You cannot do it just with html,css, and vanilla js. Are you sure that you need a **working sign in and login page** ? If not, you can try to emulate a minimal login form with pure javascript + html. This option is not recommended at all with real users, just for your school test. Is this what you need?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow social/passphrase/crypto login without being responsible for back-end code and a user's DB, check out https://overhide.io and the corresponding ledger-based authorizations.

The ["no back-end" demo](https://github.com/overhide/overhide-widgets#demos) just used public ledgers for authN and authZ.

So yes, no PHP back-end files needed here, just import the JS lib from CDN and add a couple standard Web components.  See the demos.